# Pandas : Remove rows with 0 value in the last 3 columns regardless of their name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['LCA', 'BCC', 'AAC'], 'Jul': [233, 0, 0],'Aug': [345, 0, 0],'Sep': [366, 0, 0]  })
```

[image]

I would like to drop rows with 0 in the last 3 columns regardless of their names as the names can change.
The expected result would be:
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df1[~df1.iloc[:, -3:].eq(0).all(1)]
```

output:

```
  Region  Jul  Aug  Sep
0    LCA  233  345  366
```

breaking it down:

```
# select last 3 columns by position
df1.iloc[:, -3:]

# compare to 0
.eq(0)

# are all booleans True? (i.e. are all values 0?)
.all(1)

# negate boolean
~
```

Alternative:

```
df1[df1.iloc[:, -3:].ne(0).any(1)]
```

Same as above but keeping the rows where `any` value is not 0

Comment: Why not `df1[df1.iloc[:, -3:].ne(0).any(1)]`? :-P

Comment: @Corralien IDK, just came to me like that, I'll add a note ;)

Comment: And while I realise the OP didn't ask for it... it could also be viewed as (in this sample case at least) "everything after Region"... eg: `df1.iloc[:, df1.columns.get_loc('Region') + 1:]`

Comment: @Jon yes that's true, I literally followed the "*0 in the last 3 columns*" ;)